# How do I add the necessary code to the <head> section of my wordpress site in order to display the FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I can't seem to get the calendar to show up anywhere on my site. The instructions say to add code somewhere, but I am not too familiar with CSS or Javascript. So far the  section of my site (header.php)looks like this:

```
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<?php  cryout_meta_hook(); ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php
cryout_header_hook();
wp_head(); ?>
<script $(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
})
});></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

I regret not having seen your query until the present day!!
Ok, your path it's not ok. Where you uploaded the files of FullCalendar? This function takes you to the folder of your wordpress theme: `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`
Can you try with this (insert the right path in "yourpath")?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/yourpath/fullcalendar.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/yourpath/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/yourpath/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/yourpath/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/yourpath/fullcalendar/gcal.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   })
 });
</script>
```

If you have fullcalendar files in another path (not in your Wordpress theme folder), this code will not work.

Greetings from Barcelona!!